# Are android ordered broadcasts atomic? If not how can atomicity be implemented for such broadcasts?

Tags: android, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

Suppose there are 4 `BroadcastReceivers` and there is an application sending  `Ordered Broadcast` to all of them. All four broadcast receivers are in their own separate processes. If something goes wrong in between(e.g something fails in one of the in between `onReceive` methods) how can atomicity be ensured for ordered android broadcasts?

Does it depends on use case or there is a general mechanism that can be employed?

**Update**

What `Atomicity` means exactly in case of ordered broadcast, I can only guess. For example if series of transactions are being performed in receivers, is it possible to revert all transactions upon any failure in between?
Does it even make sense to talk about `Atomicity` in this context?

Comment: It is unclear what "atomicity" has to do with broadcasts and receivers. You may wish to greatly expand your question and explain in greater detail what you mean by "atomicity" in this context.

Answer (score 1):

Android sends the ordered broadcast to each `BroadcastReceiver` serially, one after another. If something fails, Android will just continue by sending the ordered broadcast to the next `BroadcastReceiver`.

Android handles sending the ordered broadcast from a system process, so even if one of the receiver processes crashes, Android can still continue to deliver the broadcast to the next `BroadcastReceiver`.

Does that answer your question? I'm with @CommonsWare on this one as I don't know what you mean by "atomicity" in this context.

Comment: Honestly speaking, I am also not very sure. My personal opinion is talking about "Atomicity" does not make sense here. I was asked this question by someone and wanted to take opinion of community.

Comment: I have updated my question, your answer helps though!

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what you want to know.